# Separating semicolons and text from an excel cell

Tags: excel

I don't know a lot about Microsoft excel but I want to have a formula which formats a cell with semicolon separated values into different columns.

For example, **6.3; 0.48; 0.04; 1.1; 0.046; 30; 99; 0.9928; 3.24; 0.36; 9.6; 6**, how do I split up each value into different columns yet remove the semicolons?

Comment: Goto Data --> Text to Columns.  Then use the `;` as delimiter.

Comment: What did you try before posting here? It doesn't even look like you Googled it, as a solution is the [third result](https://www.google.com/search?q=Separating+semicolons+and+text+from+an+excel+cell).  @ScottCraner has your answer - in the future, please search around and try things first.  Then, if it's not working, ask specific questions about your method here.  I recommend looking over [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,";",REPT(" ",999)),COLUMNS($A:A)*999-998,999))
```

and copy across:

[image]